# Implementing strdup() in c++ exercise from Bjarne's Book, copying char* to another char* then print out gets nothing

Tags: c++, char

I'm learning c++ using the book:**Programming Principles and Practice using C++** by *Bjarne Stroustrup*.
In Chapter 19, exercise 1
implement **strdup()** functions which will copy a c strings into another using only de-referencing method (not subscripting).
My copying doesn't print anything I've been look for answers for days.
Please anyone can help me?
Below is the entire code:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char* strdup(const char* q) {
    // count the size
    int n {0};
    while(q[n]) {
        ++n;
    }
    // allocate memory
    char* p = new char[n+1];
    
    // copy q into p
    while(*q) {
        *p++ = *q++;
    }
    // terminator at the end
    p[n] = 0;
    return p;
}


int main()
{
    const char* p = "welcome";
    cout << "p:" << p << endl;

    const char* q = strdup(p);
    cout << "q:" << q << endl;
    
    // check to see if q get new address
    cout << "&p:" << &p << endl;
    cout << "&q:" << &q << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are modifying `p` which should point to beginning not end! Copy that value at the beginning and the return copy.

Comment: `p++` This changes `p` and this `return p;` returns the changed value pointing to the end rather than the start of the string.

Comment: You print `&p` and `&q` .. but those are the addresses **of the pointers**, not the pointer values you expect. So they aren't going to be all that useful. Possibly printing `static_cast<const void*>(p)` will tell you more.

Comment: You've changed the value of `p` -- it no longer points to the start of the allocated array, as @kaylum points out. Then you NUL-terminate by writing to `p[n]` .. but `p` points somewhere else and you now have undefined behavior for writing past the end of the allocated array.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/csE7Th6x1 vs https://godbolt.org/z/E7rq8Ez4v

Comment: if I use ```if``` statement instead of ```while``` loop through n times, then use ```p[i] = q [i];``` it works but de-refencing doesn't.

Comment: Please tell me the correct way of using de-referencing pointers, I'm stuck at char* thing.

Comment: Related, If you are replicating `strdup` you had better use `malloc` to do it. Sooner or later somebody is going to pass the resulting pointer to `free` if they're remotely intimate with POSIX. It won't be in ISO C until C23. Also, in `main` the var `q` shouldn't be `const char*`, it should be `char*`.

Comment: @WhozCraig You are right, I just use it that way and the first ```while```loop I used ```q[n]``` coz I want answers below correct Thanks

Comment: You all are correct from the beginning. I just don't know how to turn the pointer back to the first char. But then I tried as you pointed out and changed like this:-
   ....   `char* p_1st = p;` ... and ... `p[n] = 0;`    `return p_1st;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> using only de-referencing method (not subscripting)

So this is already wrong, because is uses the subscript operator `[]`:

```
    // count the size
    int n {0};
    while(q[n]) {
        ++n;
    }
```

> I just don't know how to turn the pointer back to the first char.

Well, there are two basic approaches:

1. stop damaging your original pointer in the first place. You can introduce new variables, remember?

   ```
   char* p_begin = new char[n+1];
   char* p_end = p_begin + n + 1; // copy the terminator too
   for (char *tmp = p_begin; tmp != p_end; *tmp++ = *q++) ;
   return p_begin;
   ```
2. you know exactly how far to move `p` to get back to the original value, because you already calculated how long the string is!

   ```
   while(*q) {
       *p++ = *q++;
   }
   *p = 0; // you already moved p and aren't supposed to be subscripting anyway
   return p - n;
   ```

Finally, you can get the size without subscripting using exactly the same technique: either you use a temporary variable to find the terminator, or if you advance `q` as you go, then subtract `n` from it again at the end.

Oh, and if you're having trouble visualizing the values of all your variables - learn to use a debugger (or just add lots of print statements). You need to understand how your state changes over time, and watching it is much more helpful than just observing the result of a black box and trying to guess what happened inside.

Comment: Finally, it's very clear how you answered it. Thanks and one more thing, Are all pointers left at the last position after looping using * (e.g ```while(*p)```)?

Comment: All variables - including pointers, are mutated when you mutate them. If you write `p++`, then `p` gets incremented. If you write `n++` then `n` gets incremented. If you alter a variable inside a loop, it's still altered when the loop finishes. You even _depend_ on changes to `n` being visible when you've finished counting the string length, so you shouldn't be surprised that changes to `p` are also visible when you've finished copying the characters.

Comment: My God! Thanks for your time! I like the * version though, it's less code, clearer!

Comment: `char* p_end = p + n + 1;` should be `char* p_end = p_begin + n + 1` right?

Comment: Correct, and fixed, thanks! I didn't compile any of this, so do check anything you use carefully.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I hope many newbies will find this helpful too if they find it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
while(*q) {
    *p++ = *q++;
}
```

..with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    p[i] = q[i];
}
```

Problem solved.

Comment: I already told that. I have to use de-referencing method. for loop works I already mentioned it in the comments. Thanks anyway. Is it possible to make the pointer turn back to the first char?

Comment: @hklsb if that is the case, than the array deference against `q` shouldn't be there either. And it can easily be done without it. [See it live](https://godbolt.org/z/dPz7xefr1).

Comment: too complex for me, I still have to learn C. @WhozCraig

Comment: @WhozCraig I kinda like that approach. Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @hklsb C and C++ are 2 different things. You have mentioned C++ in the tags of your question, which is not the same as mentioning C.

Comment: Now that it works by copying the first pointer and then returning it at the end. There must be a better way to do this. Right? It doesn't look quite right to me doing like that.

Comment: @SolvedGames you are right, I want to learn C++ but during the lesson I had to learn C as exercises so....

Comment: @hklsb The example I linked is C++. It will not work as-written on a C compiler (because there is no such thing as `static_cast<>`, nor is there `nullptr`). That example has some fairly intimate nuance to it, and if you write a var table of res, p, q, and end, then follow along single-step in a debugger or unroll it by hand it will make sense how it works. The *pointer-arithmetic* of `end-q` is probably the hardest part for a novice to understand, and worth a google.

Comment: @WhozCraig You are quite right. I thought it was C. haaaa

Comment: Now I think C++ is way more easier than C. Because C with the char* is a mystery for me.